# Javascript that saves what user typed

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, text

I have my website similar to pastebin. There is a text box on the index.php and a captcha code to complete after you finish typing to upload the paste. If you enter the wrong code, as many do, including me, a new page comes up that says you mistyped, then when you go back to index.php then everything you have written in the text box gone? Isn't cookies or cache that can save this?

Here's an GIF showing what i mean.

[image: https://gyazo.com/4db14468e5ba74837e7b9c9db5715cf9]

I think this can be fixed using some kind of javascript or cookie, i don't know which one or anything?

Please help.

EDIT: Index.php

```html
$_SESSION["dox"] = $dox;

$hidden = md5(mt_rand());
$_SESSION["hidden"] = $hidden;

$poster = md5(mt_rand());
$_SESSION["poster"] = $poster;

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
<title>CLOUDNINE BETA - TITLE</title>
<link href="style/purple.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body id="center" onload="document.getElementById('captcha-form').focus()">
<h1>WEBSITE</h1>
<p><h2><strong>Information Exchange<p></strong></h2>


<div style="color:rgb(255, 51, 51);text-shadow:rgb(194, 31, 31) 0px 1px 3px;font-size: 22px;">
<div style="margin-top:22px;margin-bottom:22px;"></div>This site is still under development, if you find any bugs, please report them to Bblaal@blabla.com</a>
</div>

<h3><a href="privacy.php">Privacy Policy</a> | <a href="/old">Old</a>  |  <a href="doxviewer.php">Archive</a> | <a href="/fail">Fail</a> | <a href="faq.php">FAQ</a>
<form action="post.php" method="post"></h3>
<p>
<input type="text" id="name" name="<?php echo $_SESSION["name"]; ?>" rows="25" cols="80" style="font-size:16px;text-align:center;font-family:Courier;color:white;border-top-left-radius:4px 4px;border-top-right-radius:4px 4px;border-bottom-right-radius:4px 4px;border-bottom-left-radius:4px 4px;background-color: rgb(30, 4, 38); border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; padding: 5px; border-color: white; " placeholder="Name"></textarea> <br />
<p>
<textarea id="dox" name="<?php echo $_SESSION["dox"]; ?>" rows="25" cols="80" placeholder="Info goes here. Post whatever info you want here. We try to stick to our strict non-removal policy, so once the post go up, they stay up unless they are shit. Asking for a post to be removed is probably the surest way for them to be updated and expanded upon.
No, this isn't doxbin."></textarea>

<p><strong>Type in the CAPTCHA here.</p><strong>
<img src="captcha.php" id="captcha" /><br/>
<a href="#" onclick="
    document.getElementById('captcha').src='captcha.php?'+Math.random();
    document.getElementById('captcha-form').focus();"
    id="change-image">Not readable? Change text.</a><br/><br/>

<input type="text" id="poster" name="<?php echo $_SESSION["poster"]; ?>" rows="25" cols="80" style="font-size:16px;text-align:center;font-family:Courier;color:white;border-top-left-radius:4px 4px;border-top-right-radius:4px 4px;border-bottom-right-radius:4px 4px;border-bottom-left-radius:4px 4px;background-color: rgb(30, 4, 38); border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; padding: 5px; border-color: white; " placeholder="Poster (Optional)"><br />
<input type="text" name="captcha" id="captcha-form" autocomplete="off" style="font-size:16px;text-align:center;font-family:Courier;color:white;border-top-left-radius:4px 4px;border-top-right-radius:4px 4px;border-bottom-right-radius:4px 4px;border-bottom-left-radius:4px 4px;background-color: rgb(30, 4, 38); margin-right:5px;border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; padding: 5px; border-color: white; " placeholder="Enter Captcha"> <br/>
<input type="submit" value="POST" style="font-size:16px;text-align:center;font-family:Courier;color:white;border-top-left-radius:4px 4px;border-top-right-radius:4px 4px;border-bottom-right-radius:4px 4px;border-bottom-left-radius:4px 4px;background-color: rgb(30, 4, 38); margin-right:5px;border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; padding: 5px; border-color: white; " /><br />
<input type="text" name="<?php echo $hidden; ?>" value="" style="visibility: hidden;" />
</p>

<?php
/** Validate captcha */
if (!empty($_REQUEST['captcha'])) {
    if (empty($_SESSION['captcha']) || trim(strtolower($_REQUEST['captcha'])) != $_SESSION['captcha']) {
        $captcha_message = "Invalid captcha";
        $style = "background-color: #FF606C";
    } else {
        $captcha_message = "Valid captcha";
        $style = "background-color: #CCFF99";
    }

    $request_captcha = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['captcha']);

    echo <<<HTML
        <div id="result" style="$style">
        <h2>$captcha_message</h2>
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Session CAPTCHA:</td>
            <td>{$_SESSION['captcha']}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Form CAPTCHA:</td>
            <td>$request_captcha</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
HTML;
    unset($_SESSION['captcha']);
}
?>

</form>



<p>
<div style="margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;text-align:center;color:white;font-size:18px;font-family:Arial;font-weight:normal;">
Follow us on Twitter: <a href="https://twitter.com/user" style="color:rgb(242, 242, 242);">@user</a>
| Contact us: <a href="mailto:blabal@gmail.com" style="color:rgb(242, 242, 242);">blabla@gmail.come</a>
| <a href="t" style="color:rgb(242, 242, 242);">Our PGP Key</a>
(Use for email) </div>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Captcha.php code:

```php
<?php
/**
 * Script para la generación de CAPTCHAS
 *
 * @author  Jose Rodriguez <jose.rodriguez@exec.cl>
 * @license GPLv3
 * @link    http://code.google.com/p/cool-php-captcha
 * @package captcha
 * @version 0.3
 *
 */


session_start();

if (!isset($_POST['captcha'])) {
    $_POST['captcha'] = "undefine";
}

$captcha = new SimpleCaptcha();



// OPTIONAL Change configuration...
//$captcha->wordsFile = 'words/es.php';
//$captcha->session_var = 'secretword';
//$captcha->imageFormat = 'png';
//$captcha->lineWidth = 3;
//$captcha->scale = 3; $captcha->blur = true;
//$captcha->resourcesPath = "/var/cool-php-captcha/resources";

// OPTIONAL Simple autodetect language example
/*
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'])) {
    $langs = array('en', 'es');
    $lang  = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
    if (in_array($lang, $langs)) {
        $captcha->wordsFile = "words/$lang.php";
    }
}
*/



// Image generation
$captcha->CreateImage();





/**
 * SimpleCaptcha class
 *
 */
class SimpleCaptcha {

    /** Width of the image */
    public $width  = 200;

    /** Height of the image */
    public $height = 60;

    /** Dictionary word file (empty for random text) */
    public $wordsFile = 'words/en.php';

    /**
     * Path for resource files (fonts, words, etc.)
     *
     * "resources" by default. For security reasons, is better move this
     * directory to another location outise the web server
     *
     */
    public $resourcesPath = 'resources';

    /** Min word length (for non-dictionary random text generation) */
    public $minWordLength = 5;

    /**
     * Max word length (for non-dictionary random text generation)
     * 
     * Used for dictionary words indicating the word-length
     * for font-size modification purposes
     */
    public $maxWordLength = 8;

    /** Sessionname to store the original text */
    public $session_var = 'captcha';

    /** Background color in RGB-array */
    public $backgroundColor = array(255, 255, 255);

    /** Foreground colors in RGB-array */
    public $colors = array(
        array(27,78,181), // blue
        array(22,163,35), // green
        array(214,36,7),  // red
    );

    /** Shadow color in RGB-array or null */
    public $shadowColor = null; //array(0, 0, 0);

    /** Horizontal line through the text */
    public $lineWidth = 0;

    /**
     * Font configuration
     *
     * - font: TTF file
     * - spacing: relative pixel space between character
     * - minSize: min font size
     * - maxSize: max font size
     */
    public $fonts = array(
        'Antykwa'  => array('spacing' => -3, 'minSize' => 27, 'maxSize' => 30, 'font' => 'AntykwaBold.ttf'),
        'Candice'  => array('spacing' =>-1.5,'minSize' => 28, 'maxSize' => 31, 'font' => 'Candice.ttf'),
        'DingDong' => array('spacing' => -2, 'minSize' => 24, 'maxSize' => 30, 'font' => 'Ding-DongDaddyO.ttf'),
        'Duality'  => array('spacing' => -2, 'minSize' => 30, 'maxSize' => 38, 'font' => 'Duality.ttf'),
        'Heineken' => array('spacing' => -2, 'minSize' => 24, 'maxSize' => 34, 'font' => 'Heineken.ttf'),
        'Jura'     => array('spacing' => -2, 'minSize' => 28, 'maxSize' => 32, 'font' => 'Jura.ttf'),
        'StayPuft' => array('spacing' =>-1.5,'minSize' => 28, 'maxSize' => 32, 'font' => 'StayPuft.ttf'),
        'Times'    => array('spacing' => -2, 'minSize' => 28, 'maxSize' => 34, 'font' => 'TimesNewRomanBold.ttf'),
        'VeraSans' => array('spacing' => -1, 'minSize' => 20, 'maxSize' => 28, 'font' => 'VeraSansBold.ttf'),
    );

    /** Wave configuracion in X and Y axes */
    public $Yperiod    = 12;
    public $Yamplitude = 14;
    public $Xperiod    = 11;
    public $Xamplitude = 5;

    /** letter rotation clockwise */
    public $maxRotation = 8;

    /**
     * Internal image size factor (for better image quality)
     * 1: low, 2: medium, 3: high
     */
    public $scale = 2;

    /** 
     * Blur effect for better image quality (but slower image processing).
     * Better image results with scale=3
     */
    public $blur = false;

    /** Debug? */
    public $debug = false;

    /** Image format: jpeg or png */
    public $imageFormat = 'jpeg';


    /** GD image */
    public $im;



    public function __construct($config = array()) {
    }


    public function CreateImage() {
        $ini = microtime(true);

        /** Initialization */
        $this->ImageAllocate();

        /** Text insertion */
        $text = $this->GetCaptchaText();
        $fontcfg  = $this->fonts[array_rand($this->fonts)];
        $this->WriteText($text, $fontcfg);

        $_SESSION[$this->session_var] = $text;

        /** Transformations */
        if (!empty($this->lineWidth)) {
            $this->WriteLine();
        }
        $this->WaveImage();
        if ($this->blur && function_exists('imagefilter')) {
            imagefilter($this->im, IMG_FILTER_GAUSSIAN_BLUR);
        }
        $this->ReduceImage();


        if ($this->debug) {
            imagestring($this->im, 1, 1, $this->height-8,
                "$text {$fontcfg['font']} ".round((microtime(true)-$ini)*1000)."ms",
                $this->GdFgColor
            );
        }


        /** Output */
        $this->WriteImage();
        $this->Cleanup();
    }



    /**
     * Creates the image resources
     */
    protected function ImageAllocate() {
        // Cleanup
        if (!empty($this->im)) {
            imagedestroy($this->im);
        }

        $this->im = imagecreatetruecolor($this->width*$this->scale, $this->height*$this->scale);

        // Background color
        $this->GdBgColor = imagecolorallocate($this->im,
            $this->backgroundColor[0],
            $this->backgroundColor[1],
            $this->backgroundColor[2]
        );
        imagefilledrectangle($this->im, 0, 0, $this->width*$this->scale, $this->height*$this->scale, $this->GdBgColor);

        // Foreground color
        $color           = $this->colors[mt_rand(0, sizeof($this->colors)-1)];
        $this->GdFgColor = imagecolorallocate($this->im, $color[0], $color[1], $color[2]);

        // Shadow color
        if (!empty($this->shadowColor) && is_array($this->shadowColor) && sizeof($this->shadowColor) >= 3) {
            $this->GdShadowColor = imagecolorallocate($this->im,
                $this->shadowColor[0],
                $this->shadowColor[1],
                $this->shadowColor[2]
            );
        }
    }





    /**
     * Text generation
     *
     * @return string Text
     */
    protected function GetCaptchaText() {
        $text = $this->GetDictionaryCaptchaText();
        if (!$text) {
            $text = $this->GetRandomCaptchaText();
        }
        return $text;
    }




    /**
     * Random text generation
     *
     * @return string Text
     */
    protected function GetRandomCaptchaText($length = null) {
        if (empty($length)) {
            $length = rand($this->minWordLength, $this->maxWordLength);
        }

        $words  = "abcdefghijlmnopqrstvwyz";
        $vocals = "aeiou";

        $text  = "";
        $vocal = rand(0, 1);
        for ($i=0; $i<$length; $i++) {
            if ($vocal) {
                $text .= substr($vocals, mt_rand(0, 4), 1);
            } else {
                $text .= substr($words, mt_rand(0, 22), 1);
            }
            $vocal = !$vocal;
        }
        return $text;
    }




    /**
     * Random dictionary word generation
     *
     * @param boolean $extended Add extended "fake" words
     * @return string Word
     */
    function GetDictionaryCaptchaText($extended = false) {
        if (empty($this->wordsFile)) {
            return false;
        }

        // Full path of words file
        if (substr($this->wordsFile, 0, 1) == '/') {
            $wordsfile = $this->wordsFile;
        } else {
            $wordsfile = $this->resourcesPath.'/'.$this->wordsFile;
        }

        if (!file_exists($wordsfile)) {
            return false;
        }

        $fp     = fopen($wordsfile, "r");
        $length = strlen(fgets($fp));
        if (!$length) {
            return false;
        }
        $line   = rand(1, (filesize($wordsfile)/$length)-2);
        if (fseek($fp, $length*$line) == -1) {
            return false;
        }
        $text = trim(fgets($fp));
        fclose($fp);


        /** Change ramdom volcals */
        if ($extended) {
            $text   = preg_split('//', $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
            $vocals = array('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u');
            foreach ($text as $i => $char) {
                if (mt_rand(0, 1) && in_array($char, $vocals)) {
                    $text[$i] = $vocals[mt_rand(0, 4)];
                }
            }
            $text = implode('', $text);
        }

        return $text;
    }




    /**
     * Horizontal line insertion
     */
    protected function WriteLine() {

        $x1 = $this->width*$this->scale*.15;
        $x2 = $this->textFinalX;
        $y1 = rand($this->height*$this->scale*.40, $this->height*$this->scale*.65);
        $y2 = rand($this->height*$this->scale*.40, $this->height*$this->scale*.65);
        $width = $this->lineWidth/2*$this->scale;

        for ($i = $width*-1; $i <= $width; $i++) {
            imageline($this->im, $x1, $y1+$i, $x2, $y2+$i, $this->GdFgColor);
        }
    }




    /**
     * Text insertion
     */
    protected function WriteText($text, $fontcfg = array()) {
        if (empty($fontcfg)) {
            // Select the font configuration
            $fontcfg  = $this->fonts[array_rand($this->fonts)];
        }

        // Full path of font file
        $fontfile = $this->resourcesPath.'/fonts/'.$fontcfg['font'];


        /** Increase font-size for shortest words: 9% for each glyp missing */
        $lettersMissing = $this->maxWordLength-strlen($text);
        $fontSizefactor = 1+($lettersMissing*0.09);

        // Text generation (char by char)
        $x      = 20*$this->scale;
        $y      = round(($this->height*27/40)*$this->scale);
        $length = strlen($text);
        for ($i=0; $i<$length; $i++) {
            $degree   = rand($this->maxRotation*-1, $this->maxRotation);
            $fontsize = rand($fontcfg['minSize'], $fontcfg['maxSize'])*$this->scale*$fontSizefactor;
            $letter   = substr($text, $i, 1);

            if ($this->shadowColor) {
                $coords = imagettftext($this->im, $fontsize, $degree,
                    $x+$this->scale, $y+$this->scale,
                    $this->GdShadowColor, $fontfile, $letter);
            }
            $coords = imagettftext($this->im, $fontsize, $degree,
                $x, $y,
                $this->GdFgColor, $fontfile, $letter);
            $x += ($coords[2]-$x) + ($fontcfg['spacing']*$this->scale);
        }

        $this->textFinalX = $x;
    }



    /**
     * Wave filter
     */
    protected function WaveImage() {
        // X-axis wave generation
        $xp = $this->scale*$this->Xperiod*rand(1,3);
        $k = rand(0, 100);
        for ($i = 0; $i < ($this->width*$this->scale); $i++) {
            imagecopy($this->im, $this->im,
                $i-1, sin($k+$i/$xp) * ($this->scale*$this->Xamplitude),
                $i, 0, 1, $this->height*$this->scale);
        }

        // Y-axis wave generation
        $k = rand(0, 100);
        $yp = $this->scale*$this->Yperiod*rand(1,2);
        for ($i = 0; $i < ($this->height*$this->scale); $i++) {
            imagecopy($this->im, $this->im,
                sin($k+$i/$yp) * ($this->scale*$this->Yamplitude), $i-1,
                0, $i, $this->width*$this->scale, 1);
        }
    }




    /**
     * Reduce the image to the final size
     */
    protected function ReduceImage() {
        // Reduzco el tamaño de la imagen
        $imResampled = imagecreatetruecolor($this->width, $this->height);
        imagecopyresampled($imResampled, $this->im,
            0, 0, 0, 0,
            $this->width, $this->height,
            $this->width*$this->scale, $this->height*$this->scale
        );
        imagedestroy($this->im);
        $this->im = $imResampled;
    }



    /**
     * File generation
     */
    protected function WriteImage() {
        if ($this->imageFormat == 'png' && function_exists('imagepng')) {                header("Content-type: image/png");
            imagepng($this->im);
        } else {
            header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
            imagejpeg($this->im, null, 80);
        }
    }



    /**
     * Cleanup
     */
    protected function Cleanup() {
        imagedestroy($this->im);
    }
}




?>
```

Comment: Put some code so we can help you (give code of both pages)

Comment: @ShanKhaliq Done so, please check :=)

Comment: @MirreJake Welcome to SO. Could you please avoid using offensive words (specifically in the gif)?. Thank you

Comment: @Mariano Hello, yes im very sorry for that.

Comment: @Mariano, you said that you edited everything, im very glad for that but im so new to SO and i don't know which part of the code you edited. Is it the green? The red with a line on it? Sorry. Look here: https://gyazo.com/882b72b345029f0b67c739c3db811c47 its very confusing.

Comment: you can use $_SESSION to store values, or you can make ajax request to perform you actions

Comment: @MirreJake I simply changed the code formatting and removed the extra blank lines for readability, nothing in the code was changed.

Comment: Oh okay, my fault (pretty new to SO). Well do you have any tips how i can make this posiible? Please vote up this so more can read and help.

Answer (score 1):

The text box content and the captcha response are both posted to post.php when the form is submitted.  If the captcha verification fails, send the text box content along with the failure in a form that links back to index.php so the content can be used as the initial value of the text box.

Or use ajax to send the text and captcha, waiting for either a success message and link to follow, or an error with a new captch.  In the case of an error, display a message and the new captcha so the user can try again, and the page doesn't reload until there is a success.

Comment: instead of submitting the form normally, submit via ajax and have the post.php file respond with a specific error.  Your success callback could then show the failure message in the appropriate place and change the captcha in the same manner as your 'not readable' link

Answer (score 0):

Please Put the validation process on the same page.
Means you have a `post.php` page which do the validation and than process the data please put the validation process on the same `index.php` page. and you can also use the idea of JOE of using AJAX call.

By doing this you can get the data you have posted on the page as well to put it back on the `index` and the benefit of this you can get the error of captcha on the same page as well.

If you give the full code of index.php and post.php than i can fix this in a blink. hope you get the point.